# $g(x)=(f(x) -f(a))^2$ is differentiable at $a$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let there be some open interval $U$ in $\mathbb R$ that accommodates the point $a$. Prove that if $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz continuous, then $g(x)=(f(x) -f(a))^2$ is differentiable at $a$.

I need help with this question, but please if you can, hints would be way way more helpful for me in the long run.

Currently I'm starting with the Lipshitz definition which is that there exists $K$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < K|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$, and I'm attempting to haggle it towards the differentiable definition, that is that $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{g(x) -g(a)}{x-a}$$ exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guide:

Notice that we have $g(a) = 0 $.

Hence we are interested in

$$\lim_{x \to a} \left|\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\right|=\lim_{x \to a} \left|\frac{(f(x)-f(a))^2}{x-a}\right|$$

Try to use Lipschitz condition twice.

Comment: Why twice?  Once should suffice...

Comment: Yup, once suffices actually.